# Textbox Delete Button not Undoing

Tags: vb.net

Basically the code below deletes the selected text from a textbox, although you cannot undo it. Any help on making it undo?

```
TextBox1.SelectedText = ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a variation of the following...

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim selText as String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        selText = TextBox1.SelectedText
        TextBox1.SelectedTexxt = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox1.AppendText(selText)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -2):

Found an answer. Just use this code below

```
SendKeys.Send("{BS}")
```

Comment: `SendKeys` is an unreliable method!